# When should you perform a Jackknife sensitivity analysis in a meta analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, jackknife

I am currently doing a meta analysis looking at sleep outcomes. In the paper I perform 6 different meta analysis (based on 6 different sleep outcomes). I want to do a sensitivity analysis on the results using the Jackknife method, but I was wondering if there was any "rules" to which data you should perform the analysis on (i.e, only significant results, only results which show heterogeneity etc).

Comment: For clarification, do you mean Jackknife sensitivity analyses as in removing one study at a time and seeing if there is a major change in the effect estimate, CIs or statistical heterogeneity?